# Fabrics 2.x ssh connection using identity fails to work

Tags: python, ssh, fabric, python-fabric-2

Trying to connect to the host described in ssh config using fabrics 2 and identity file.

```
con = Connection('my_host')
@task
def tt(c):
    con.run('uname -a')
```

~/.ssh/config :

```
Host my_host
    HostName 123.144.76.84
    User ubuntu
    IdentityFile ~/.keys/somekey
```

It fails with

> paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed.

While `$ ssh my_host` from the terminal works.

I've tried to do `fab -i  ~/.keys/somekey tt` with same result.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be something afoot with `paramiko`. Without digging deeper I don't know if it's a bug or not. In any case, I had the same issue, and even a plain `paramiko` call got me the same error.

Following [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71140149/160665) I was able to make it work by disabling `rsa-sha2-256` and `rsa-sha2-512` as mentioned.

Luckily, `fabric` exposes access to the paramiko arguments like so:

```py
con = Connection(
    'my_host',
    connect_kwargs={
        "disabled_algorithms": {"pubkeys": ["rsa-sha2-256", "rsa-sha2-512"]}
    }
)
```

I find it unlucky that this is required in the fabfile. If someone else has a better/cleaner solution feel free to comment.

Answer (score 1):

Fabric [accepts a hosts iterable](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/2.4/api/tasks.html#fabric.tasks.task) as parameters in tasks. Per the documentation:

> An iterable of host-connection specifiers appropriate for eventually instantiating a Connection. The existence of this argument will trigger automatic parameterization of the task when invoked from the CLI, similar to the behavior of --hosts.

One of the members of which could be:

> A string appropriate for being the first positional argument to Connection - see its docs for details, but these are typically shorthand-only convenience strings like hostname.example.com or user@host:port.

As for your example, please try this for fabfile.py:

```
host_list = ["my_host"]

@task(hosts=host_list)
def tt(c):
    c.run('uname -a')
```

Alternatively, you can omit the host declaration from the fabfile altogether. If you don't specify the host in `fabfile.py`, you can simply specify it as a host when invoking the `fab` cli utility. If your fabfile.py is this:

```
@task
def tt(c):
    c.run('uname -a')
```

You would now run `fab -H my_host tt` to run it on the alias `tt` from your SSH client config.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, it leads to the same result. 
`
...
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 437, in connect
    passphrase,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 749, in _auth
    raise saved_exception
paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed.`

Comment: First suggestion is not working at all - complaining on hosts parameter. Its not related to the question

Comment: I believe the problem is that for some reason its trying to use password to auth instead of provided cert

Comment: I'm out of ideas. Have you already tried adding your private key to the SSH agent? `ssh-add ~/.keys/somkey`

Answer (score 0):

Same problem.

You can try add `-d` for more detail when fabric run:

```sh
fab2 -d tt
```

I found the exception: `paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Invalid key`, then regenerate key from server, problem solved.